# C# - calling one method inside another within the same class

Tags: c#, methods

I have 2 methods:

```
static int CalculateParity(string encodedHamming, int parityBit)
    {
        //Code here
    }

static string CalculateHamming(string rawByte)
{
     //Code here
}
```

Inside the main method (all of these are in the same class) I want to call the first two methods. I understand normally it would be

```
CalculateHamming();
CalculateParity();
```

To call them, however I'm not sure how to call them because the methods have definitions. I had a look around stack overflow and other sites but I can't find anything. If someone could explain to me how to do this or link me to something similar I may have missed that would be great, thanks!

Comment: You have to pass arguments for `encodedHamming`, `parityBit`, and `rawByte`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ClassName.MethodName` so if the class was called `Calculations`, like below:

```
static class Calculations
{
    static int CalculateParity(string encodedHamming, int parityBit)
    {
            //Code here
    }

    static string CalculateHamming(string rawByte)
    {
         //Code here
    }
}
```

Inside main would be like:

```
main()
{
    string rawBtye;
    Calculations.CalculateHamming(rawBtye);
}
```

If you want to call `CalculateParity` inside `CalculateHamming` you don't need the ClassName before:

```
static string CalculateHamming(string rawByte)
{
     CalculateParity(encodedHamming, parityBit);
}
```

Comment: All of the methods are inside the same class `Program`. I had already tried what you suggested in your final piece of code with errors saying encodedHamming and parityBit don't exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first get some clue about the basic concepts.

here [methods/functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm)
and here [classes](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/introduction/)

Your program's structure should be something similar to this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    void Function1()
    {
    }

    void Function2()
    {
    }
}
```

Nonetheless, I advise you learning the concepts first, then solving your particular issue.

Comment: I understand the concepts of classes and methods, and my program does look like that. @Harb

Comment: What is the question then?